# How to display multiple values without multiple select on initialization?

Tags: jquery, select, initialization, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

I am trying to initialize as same as normal dropdown list with one value selected using select2

```
    $("#e5").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        query: function (query) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url:'/ajax',
                params: {'val' : query.term}
            }).then(function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                query.callback(data);
            });          
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var obj= {id:1,text:'whatever value'};            
            callback(obj);
        }
    });
```

Is there a way something like this below in initialization or similar with multiple values and others are just displayed without setting multipleSelect as true in select2 configuration.

```
var preload_data = [
      { id: 'user0', text: 'Disabled User', selected: true}
      , { id: 'user1', text: 'Jane Doe'}
      , { id: 'user2', text: 'John Doe'}
      , { id: 'user3', text: 'Robert Paulson'}
      , { id: 'user5', text: 'Spongebob Squarepants'}
      , { id: 'user6', text: 'Planet Bob' }
      , { id: 'user7', text: 'Inigo Montoya' }
    ];    

    initSelection : function (element, callback) {                  
        callback(preload_data);
    }
```

Any suggestions will be grateful in advance

Comment: you can use `tags` option as well

Comment: @VenkataPanga, Thanks for your reply. I tried using tags as an option before init passing an array like ** tags:["red", "green", "blue"]** and tags : preload_data, both seems not to work for me. Can you correct me with this...